# How to determine if two confidence intervals are statistically different

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I need help with calculating the confidence intervals for the difference of two dependent means. Literature on the same for independent means is readily available but does anyone know how to do it for two dependent means?

Comment: If you can estimate $\delta = \mu_1 - \mu_2$ then you want a CI for $\delta.$ // How about describing the context. How do the two means arise? What is the structure of the dependence? Is the population distribution normal? What do you hope to learn from the confidence interval?

Comment: @BruceET, 1) correct I want a CI for δ. I have run mark-recapture analysis on leopard census data. The study design involves increasing sampling effort by increasing the number of recapture events. For each sampling effort, I generated population estimates (which themselves are means) and their corresponding confidence intervals. I need to establish a cut-off point where there is no significant difference in the population estimate with increasing sampling effort.

Comment: 2) Ordinarily, one can do this by calculating the confidence intervals of the difference between two means, provided the data are independent. In my case, each population estimate (or mean) is partially dependent upon those from preceding sampling efforts. How can I determine the statistical difference of these means?

Comment: Need to know structure of 'partial' association. Are sample sizes for the two means the same? If so,  do you have meaningful pairs $(X_1, Y_1),$ etc. If so, what is the sample correlation $r_{X,Y}?$